# Should we clean up Hinduism chat?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

It seems that main chat has become a place mainly for Hinduism bot. It used to be that members would actually chat there, but it seems to have languished. Should we perhaps have a second chat for Hinduism bot so that main chat can become a place of community again?

Answer (score 3):

> Should we perhaps have a second chat for Hinduism bot so that main chat can become a place of community again?

No, we do not need a separate chat-rooms for bot and users. Doing that will probably vanish the purpose for which bot/feed has been created! Usually feeds are created to notify the chat users (who can become very busy in chatting! lol) about what's happening at site. Users belonging to other sites also visit our chat room occasionally to find their interest.

[image]

But in our case the participation of chat users has become quite rare and hence the room contains feeds posted by chatbot only.

**We can remove or alter some feeds but I don't think we need a separate room for that.**

Actually what we need is participation of users in the chat-room. I think if Stack Exchange provides a modern Android App incorporating site functionality, moderation ability and chat features, then mobile users would enjoy and engage in site and rooms more effectively.

Comment: Ji What is this common chatroom and how can i join it??

Comment: [Here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=hinduism.stackexchange.com) is the link for chat. Here you will find all active chatrooms related to Hinduism SE. And [this is the link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) for the particular chatroom. @Rāmachandra

Comment: Thank you @Rickross Ji!